# Android Studio: Gradle build fails -- Execution failed for task ':compileDebugAidl'

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

After changes to source and building with gradle in Android Studio (I/O preview) AI - 130.677228 the build fails with the following error:

```
Gradle: 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugAidl'.
> No signature of method: com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasks() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
  Possible solutions: waitForAllTasks()
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
```

The second time running a build the build will succeed.

Using a gradle wrapper with version 1.6

This really sucks because it does a long build (non-incremental) after it fails the first time.

Is there a way to not have this failure?

EDIT to include build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.6'
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:17"
    buildToolsVersion "17"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

Link to issue on Google Code: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56158

Comment: Did you try building from command line with --stacktrace --info --debug gradle flags?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky This issue is fixed. It was fixed in a gradle version almost two years ago.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure how this is possible. It looks like you have a mismatch between the Gradle plugin itself and its dependencies that provides the WaitableExecutor class.

However you mention Gradle 1.5 and this is a problem.

The plugin version 0.3 was compatible with Gradle 1.3-1.4
The new version release last week, 0.4 is compatible with Gradle 1.6+

Make sure you use 0.4 and the new Gradle version.

Comment: I'm using Gradle 1.6 and plugin version 0.4 and have the same issue.
My build file: http://pastebin.com/WCP1R4uW

Comment: (false positive on new android build fixing it)
I'm now on 1.6 and version 0.4-- I've added my build.gradle file above.

Comment: I should mention that it's still broken with 1.6 and version 0.4

Comment: yeah, there was indeed a problem. It's fixed for the next version. I'm hoping to release something quickly.

Comment: Yay @Xav! Thanks for taking a look at it. :D
I'll be able to verify your fix here.

Answer (score 36):

I solved this issue by setting `buildToolsVersion` in my `build.gradle` file to match the latest version of the Android SDK Build-tools in the SDK manager.

[image: Showing Build-tools version 22.0.1 is installed]

In my case, I have the Android SDK Build-tools version **22.0.1** installed, so I set `buildToolsVersion` accordingly:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
...
```

After making that change, my app builds uneventfully.

Comment: Hah, just had this problem after updating Android Studio. Found this question with google. Your answer solved my problem and despite the question is 2 years old you answered it just 3 hours ago. Crazy :).

Comment: Looks like the latest version of android studio at the time 1.2.1 comes bundled with buildToolsVersion 23.0.0 rc1.  Not a good idea to release a release candidate in a stable build.

Comment: @bonth: how you found out the build version? i had same problem, with `compile SdkVersion 22` and `buildToolsVersion 23.0.0 rc` and had same problem. but when i changed it to `22.0.1` my problem solved

Comment: @MoHradA I've edited the answer to include an image of the Build-tools version in Android SDK Manager.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue *"Failed to execute the task: compileDebugaidl aidl/debug/".*

I saw further in Gradle Console for the specifics and it read as below:

*Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task 'prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library' during up-to-date check.*

*Could not remove entry '/Users/..../.../.../..../build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3' from cache outputFileStates.bin (/Users/..../..../..../.gradle/2.2.1/taskArtifacts/outputFileStates.bin).*

I resolved it by deleting the **outputFileStates.bin** file from the terminal and allowed Gradle to recreate it.

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Add:

`compileSdkVersion 17` to your buid.gradel file (below).

And use version 3 of the plugin: `com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.3` (or higher for future questions,etc)

**Edit**: reference project I just created. Builds, signs,etc https://github.com/yegdroid/gradle_demo

```
//
// A basic Android application that follows all the conventions
//
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    testBuildType = "debug"

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "0.1"
        minSdkVersion = 9
        targetSdkVersion = 17


        compileSdkVersion 17
        buildConfig "private final static boolean DEFAULT = true;", \
                    "private final static String FOO = \"foo\";"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packageNameSuffix = ".debug"

            buildConfig "private final static boolean DEBUG2 = false;"
        }
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "txt"
    }
    sourceSets {
          main {
              manifest {
                  srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
              }
              java {
                  srcDir 'src'
              }
              res {
                  srcDir 'res'
              }
              assets {
                  srcDir 'assets'
              }
              resources {
                  srcDir 'src'
              }
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: Does that mean your question isn't really an issue anymore?

Comment: I need to compile against the google apis for 17. See build.gradle above.

Comment: why do you have compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:17" just need compileSdkVersion "17"

Comment: Doesn't compile if I have just '17' -- it's missing the maps import.

Comment: which version of gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: it's in the gradle build file. I'm using the wrapper with v 1.6

Answer (score 1):

Add the code below into your build.gradle file. This works for me.

```
dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, try checking "Use default gradle wrapper" option in the Project-level settings.

Android Studio --> File --> Settings --> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Build Tools --> Gradle

Answer (score 0):

Like to register my problem and solution here since it is almost relevent to the issue posted that if someone stumbles across the error could overcome it quickly.

I faced a similar issue with Failed to execute the task: compileDebugaidl aidl/debug/.. Access is denied ...

I overcame the issue by deleting the build directory and rebuilding it again[I'm using the Gradle 0.14.4]

Comment: What is path to build directory? Is it `./android/.gradle`?

Comment: Wow I deleted all files inside of `./android/.gradle/2.14.1/taskArtifacts/` and re-ran and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me
**edit in your project build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        //delete this line below   
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'
        //add this line below
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The missing AIDL something is google android studio problem to not update major gradle dependencies class path.

Fix:
- open project gradle file (no app, project !)
- replace:
**classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1' or whatever** 
with
**classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'**

If you can not compile a time before, compilable project, the google cat & dog are not sleeping and theire making changes, updates, therefore you have to wake up and made changes where they forget to. 
And gradle is quite unstable project and buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Can i see gradle (error filtered) output? (toolwindow gradle, gradle tab)
Looks like there is problem with functions inside the aidl files, which are mostly for outside application interface, & services.
Etc to transfer data to widget, or if you need data transfer between two applications.
Second posibility is two libraries with the same aidl structure, just one function is differrent, than one, or you are using the same library twice.
Another reason i newer saw with this message