# Cannot build gradle on Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

When i try to run my app on emulator, android studio show me this error

[image]

Here is my gradle.app code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.gdp.censos"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?, i have try everything...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682443/android-studio-gradle-build-fails-execution-failed-for-task-compiledebugai